# Não consigo entender esse tipo de import

Tags: python, import

Sou iniciante no Python é me deparei com uma coisa que eu não entendi:

```
import pygame

from pygame.sprite import Sprite

    class Bullet(Sprite):

        def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen,ship):
```

Minha pergunta é o que seria `pygame.sprite import Sprite`?

Comment: `from pygame.sprite import Sprite` significa: *Do módulo pygame.sprite importe a classe Sprite*. <(-_-)>

Comment: sprite é um submodulo ?

Comment: Qual a parte de **Do módulo pygame.sprite importe a classe Sprite.** você não entendeu?

Comment: é o pygame.sprite

Comment: Você tem a lib pygame, além da lib principal ela dividida em vários outros módulos, um para cada assunto. Então pode se entender como submodulo especializado, mas na realidade são módulos inclusos ou aninhados.

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro `import` carregará o módulo **pygame** no escopo (*namespace*) do teu arquivo/módulo enquanto que o segundo carregará apenas a classe "Sprite" nele. Na verdade o segundo `import` está aí como um atalho já que nada te impede de escrever:

```py
import pygame

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ...
```

Talvez só a praticidade já que "Sprite" é bem menor que "pygame.sprite.Sprite". :-)

Pois do ponto de vista da linguagem eles correspondem ao mesmo objeto:

```
>>> import pygame
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
t>>> id(pygame.sprite.Sprite)
43004016
>>> from pygame.sprite import Sprite
>>> id(Sprite)
43004016
```

Comment: Mano valeu !!! Vc pode me indicar algum lugar para ver como funciona esses modulos aninhados ?

Comment: @kyo129, se a resposta é útil o ajudou você pode votar e a aceitar como resposta correta: Veja, [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/137387),  [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/137387) e [Como dizer obrigado em respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)